# Change the appearance of reference list

Tags: xetex, natbib

I cite a Chinese paper and want to change the "and" in the references list to "&". And keep citation style of the English paper.

mini example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{fanziyin2010} emphasizes the interaction between temliness and demand uncertainty.

\medskip
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file (`citation.bib`)

```
@article{fanziyin2010,
Author = {范子英 and 张军},
Date-Added = {2016-11-05 15:26:38 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-11-06 06:10:56 +0000},
Journal = {经济研究},
Number = {3},
Pages = {53--64},
Title = {财政分权, 转移支付与国内市场整合},
Volume = {45},
Year = {2010}}

@article{eaton2002technology,
Author = {Eaton, Jonathan and Kortum, Samuel},
Journal = {Econometrica},
Number = {5},
Pages = {1741--1779},
Publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
Title = {Technology, geography, and trade},
Volume = {70},
Year = {2002}}
```

IDE:Texpad 1.731

Engine: Xelatex, BibTex

Compiled output of the mini example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to reaplace spaces by `~` and replace the `and` by your character. It should result like all the names are just one name. `Maestro~Glanz` behaves like `Maestroglanz` (it's not recognized as prename and surname, but one name).  `Maestro Glanz` is recognized as prename and surname. I'm not sure if this works, but it could.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz but I don't want to change the citation call-outs.

Comment: I had a second Look at your example. Do you use babel?

Comment: No, I use a similar edit tool.

Comment: This is normally covered by the babel package. You could load babel and your package after that. That could or should work. Please refer to other users by @username. Only the OP isnt addressed by name.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz I edit my question again.